# R: Create fast FIFO like list of stock transactions

Tags: r, finance

I am having a number of stock transactions where the number of stocks is given by Quantity. The cumulative sum of Quantity cannot become negative (*cumsum(Quantity) will never be negative*), as I will always first buy then sell. For example:

```
Quantity <- c(3,-1,-2,3,-1,2,-4)
```

Now I would like to create a list of trades, where each trade has to have the same number of stocks bought and sold (*sum(TradeN)==0*). The list of trades should follow the FIFO principle. So first units bought are the first units sold again.

So the first trade in the example would be a buy of 1 unit and then a sell of 1.

```
Trade1 <- c(1,-1)
```

leaving us with the following transactions

```
Quantity <- c(2,-2,3,-1,2,-4)
```

In the end I would like to have something like:

```
PurchaseSale <- list(Trade1=c(1,-1), Trade2=c(2,-2), Trade3=c(1,-1), Trade4=c(2,2,-4))
```

I have written a rather clumsy version for this which is quite slow involving many loops. So maybe someone has an idea of how to solve this problem in a fast way as my Quantity vector may be very large.

Comment: I don't get it. For a given vector like Quantity you want a list like your PurchaseSale that does what? Are you applying each element to Quantity sequentially?  So after Trade2 you have c(0,0,3,-1,2,4)? But then Trade3 makes it c(-1,1,3,-1,2,4)? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I would like to reorder Quantity to PurchaseSale where each item in PurchaseSale has to satisfy mapply(sum, PurchaseSale) == 0. 
Yes, I am applying each element to Quantity sequentially? After Trade2 Quantity would be c(0,0,0,3,-1,2,-4) and after Trade3 c(0,0,0,2,0,2,-4) or c(3,-1,2,-4) and c(2,2,-4) if you remove the 0's.